# Potential difference between charged plates

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

Is the potential difference between the two plates only due to the charges on the inner sides of the plates or due to total charges on both plates?Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The charges on the inner side of the plates must be equal in magnitude but opposite in sign .This can be acheived because the capacitor will redistribute its charges and facing surfaces always have equal and opposite charges,and that charge becomes the charge of the capacitor of which the potential difference between the plates can be easily found out.